# How to programatically copy selected data?

Tags: c#, .net, copy

I am trying to bind for example the copy action to one of my mouse buttons. I've managed to get it to work with volume up or down with the following code:

```
 private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
 private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
 private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
 private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;

    IntPtr handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    public void Mute()
    {
        SendMessageW(handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, handle,
            (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
    }

    public void VolDown()
    {
        SendMessageW(handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, handle,
            (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
    }

    public void VolUp()
    {
        SendMessageW(handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, handle,
            (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
    }
```

Now I want to do the same thing with copy. I tried to do it with key events and just simulate the key presses, but that doesn't work too well. So I tried to figure out what the constant was for the COPY command. This is what I found in the Microsoft docs:
[image]
But if I define the command as `private const int APPCOMMAND_COPY = 0x360000`, it just doesn't work. So I tried to convert that number to hex and changed it to `private const int APPCOMMAND_COPY = 0x240000`. But that doesn't work either.

Am I doing something wrong here or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/wm-copy

Comment: @Nick Doesn't work :(

Comment: try setting the `APPCOMMAND_COPY = 0x000036`

Comment: Well, COPY command relies on a selected text in a control, or some other active control that supports copy operation.  When you mouse click, you likely remove the selection and there is nothing to copy.

Comment: @MindSwipe Unfortunately this doesn't work either.

Comment: @Nick the thing is I have an interface where I set the actions to my buttons. Whenever there is something connected to a button, I block the original click and execute the action. So I don't think I remove the selection